# COM event handling works in VBScript but not Javascript (JScript)

Tags: javascript, com, event-handling

I wrote an application implementing COM and scripting. Calling methods works in both VBScript and JavaScript (JScript), but event handling only in VBScript.

The COM object is called Ftp and has a method "display" and an event "Main" which is fired on starting the script engine.
The answers I could find mostly concerns Web pages, not simple scripts.

Working VBScript:

```
Ftp.display 2,"VBScript started"&vbNewLine

Sub Ftp_Main()
    Ftp.display 12,"Main event fired"&vbNewLine
End Sub
```

Displayed:

VBScript started

Main event fired

Non-working JavaScript:

```
Ftp.display(2,"JavaScript started\n");

function Ftp::Main()
{
    Ftp.display(4,"Main event fired!\n");
}
```

Only "JavaScript started" is displayed.

I don't think the problem is with the JScript syntax, but with my implementation of the scripting host. I debugged how the scripting host is called in the case of both VBScript and JScript and noticed the following differences:
In the VBScript case AutoProxy::XActiveScriptSite::GetItemInfo() is called with dwReturnMask==SCRIPTINFO_IUNKNOWN and then dwReturnMask==SCRIPTINFO_ITYPEINFO. After that AutoProxy::XMyContainer::FindConnectionPoint() is called.
In the JScript case AutoProxy::XActiveScriptSite::GetItemInfo(SCRIPTINFO_ITYPEINFO) is not called and neither is AutoProxy::XMyContainer::FindConnectionPoint().
It is thus no surprise that in the event code pConPt->GetStartPosition() returns NULL.
I have been unable to find any unmanaged code where JScript events work.

Answer (score 0):

Gerrtvn probe change Ftp::Main to Ftp_Main

ps: I think Gerrtvn you came from C++ world.